# Syntax error in sudoers file

Tags: debian, sudo, brightness

I wanted to allow my ordinary user to run `/usr/bin/brightnessctl` to turn on/off the keyboard backlight on my laptop, so I did

```
visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/grove
```

(`grove` is my username, but all that matters here is that that file is included in `/etc/sudoers`)

That file already contained these lines:

```
grove   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/light -A 5
grove   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/light -U 5
```

so I just mimicked those and tried adding

```
grove   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/brightnessctl -d tpacpi::kbd_backlight s 2
grove   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/brightnessctl -d tpacpi::kbd_backlight s 0
```

but that make `visudo` report a syntax error:

```
/etc/sudoers.d/grove:3:59: syntaksfejl
grove   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/brightnessctl -d tpacpi::kbd_backlight s 2
                                                          ^~
/etc/sudoers.d/grove:4:59: syntaksfejl
grove   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/brightnessctl -d tpacpi::kbd_backlight s 0
                                                          ^~
```

(`syntaksfejl` is Danish for `syntax error`, I have `LANG` set so everything speaks Danish, and I see no reason to redo it with `LANG=C` to provide an error in english for such little text)

What is wrong here? Is it the colons (and the indicator being wrong, which might be caused by a TAB after `grove`), and if so how can I allow that command? Should I just allow `/usr/bin/brightnessctl` and accept that I can control more things?

(If it matters, I'm working on a Debian 12)

Comment: Have you tried backslash escaping the colons, as indicated in the ['Aliases' section of the sudoers manual](https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/sudoers.man/#Aliases) ?

Comment: No, I had tried quoting the arguments, as that normally achieves the same, but I should have read the documentation because that worked.

Comment: Could one of you (Henrik or @steeldriver) please post that as an answer?

Comment: I was thinking of it, but I want to give @steeldriver time to do so.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity go for it! You've actually verified it, it haven't ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment @steeldriver pointed out that the ['Aliases' section of the sudoers manual](https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/sudoers.man/#Aliases) said that the colons must be escaped with a `\`, and that worked.

I had foolishly not bothered to read the manual, but had fruitlessly tried to quote my way out of it, as that often accomplishes the same, but as said the `\`'s worked.